# SwiftUI - Does anyone know how Family Control works?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, parental-control

I have a problem about Family Control in iOS 16.
I would like to create an app for parental control, I mean pairing two devices then controlling the child one,
the documentation is pretty lacking
I implemented Manage Settings, Device Activity Extension, and Family Controls as it was said in WWDC:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110336/

As they said, sending a request when app launched,

```
@main
struct PCDemoAppApp: App {
//    iOS 15 requesforauth appDelegate method
//    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {

            ContentView()
                .onAppear{
//                WWDC iOS 16 request
                Task{
                    do{
                        try await AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: .child)
                    }catch{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then, i am listing the apps which one if any in my app, starting monitoring etc...
When I select the apps in my app, **it gives restriction to your own applications not the childs....**

The real question is,
Now, I got 2 iCloud accounts, one of the parent and other one is child. Both logged in 2 phones right now.
I building my app both, child sends request -want to enable access to screen time etc. - but parent one is not.
I can monitoring childs apps in parent but I can not restricted which is selected in parent, **it gives restriction to your own applications not the childs even only childs screen time enabled in parent device**. I could not understand that part,

Is there any missing part of Screen Time API?
How can I test it?
Why can't i give restriction for child?
Is it correct to get builds on both devices?

Is there any missing part of Screen Time API?How can I test it? Why can't i give restriction for child?Is it correct to get builds on both devices?

Im using that example for monitoring
https://www.folio3.com/mobile/blog/screentime-api-ios/